# firefox failing a post request - NS_BINDING_ABORTED

Tags: firefox, autosave, asynchronous-javascript

My case - "form data to be auto saved before navigating to new page". Firefox is cancelling form post with "NS_BINDING_ABORTED" and navigating to new page. Body - onbeforeunload is used to post the form. is there a way to tell Firefox to don't cancel the call (form post)?

post and get calls in one action. post is Asynchronous. Firefox is blocking post with **NS_BINDING_ABORTED** and proceeding with get call.

**Solution:** setTimeout(postFunctionName,0);

Comment: It is resolved  setTimeout(functionName,0);